# DataStore for Certificates and Keys

Tags: database, certificate

I am developing a web application. It is a multitenant(SAAS) application.
  My application involves getting signed certificates from users. Obviously each certificate would be having a separate CSR and Private Keys.
I need to retain all those things for further processing. I know that I can save those details in a table in my database and later use it. 
 But I am not sure whether it is a good way of storing certificates and keys. 

Is there any ideal way to store certificates rather than a table?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a table?

Comment: I am pretty good with the table. But I want to know is there any ideal way of maintaining these data since private keys are involved.?

Comment: Are you asking how to secure the private keys?  I don't think the method of storage is going to matter all that much; an XML file containing the keys is going to be no more or less secure than a database table.  Your application is still going to need access to them, so it's either going to be some application-level security ID for the database table, or a folder that is only available to the application and to administrators for the XML file.  For multi-tenancy, the database table is going to be far more convenient to access and maintain, and to secure, for that matter.

Comment: RobertHarvey, Thanks for the heads up and your suggestion!